# Classic ASP javascript check parent

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, frame, jscript

I am using a Classic ASP file (language = JavaScript) to display some HTML information. What I want to do is check if the page is in a frame, and if not, redirect to another page. Is there a way of checking if a page has a parent in Classic ASP? I've tried using `window`, but it isn't recognised. The code should be something like this:

```
<%@ language = "JavaScript"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Secure Area</title>

        <link href="css/basic.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />

        <%
            if (!window.parent)
                window.location.replace("index.html");
        %>

        <link href="Images/FavIcon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really.

Browsers do not send information about frame structure to the server when they request a resource.

You could check the HTTP Referer header (it is optional so it might not be defined), make an HTTP request (using your server side code) back to that URI, then parse it to see if it contains any frames, and if any of them default to `src="your uri"` or if any links targetting a frame have `href="your uri"` … but that would be very inefficient and unreliable.

This sort of thing is better handled with client side JS.

Comment: Yeah, thought so. Client side JS can be turned off though.

Answer (score 1):

You can't check if a window is in a frame on the server side - there is nothing in the request that gives you this information.

You need to do this client side - you can have your *client side* script pass the values to the server (parameter on the URL, hidden field, cookie, whatever...).

Answer (score 1):

In javascript you can check if a page is in an iframe with this:

```
if (window.top === window.self) {
    // not in a frame
} else {
    // in a frame
}
```

There is no way to do this in ASP. No server side language would be aware of if its being rendered in a frame or not - it is not it's business knowing.